# How to create a summary (i.e. total row) for each column in a ff.create_annotated_heatmap figure in addition to x and y axis text

Tags: plotly

The following image was made using the code below

```
df_corr_round = df_corr.round(3)
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=df_corr_round.to_numpy(),
            x=df_corr.columns.tolist(),
            y=df_corr.index.tolist(),
            zmax=1, zmin=-1,
            showscale=True,
            hoverongaps=True
            )
# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='<i><b>Correlation round</b></i>')
```

How can I create a new xaxis below each column which algebraically adds all the columns. Something like a summary (total row below with white background and bold text) without adding anything to the original dataframe.

[image]

titanic heatmap:

[image: titanic heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations to handle the total values, but I think the way to add the aggregation table as a subplot looks better. I wrote the code thinking that it would be easy to achieve this by combining the annotated heatmap with the same create table, but it didn't work. So I used `make_subplots()` to handle it. There may be an easier way to write the annotations for the numbers. The tally includes '1.00', so you need to be creative to exclude it.

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

df_corr = titanic.corr()
df_corr_round = df_corr.round(3)

tbl = df_corr_round.sum(axis=1).to_frame()
tbl = tbl.T
tbl.rename(index={0:'sum'})

# columns data create
tbl_data = []
for x in tbl.values[0]:
    tbl_data.append([round(x,3)])

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, 
                    row_heights=[0.8, 0.2],
                    vertical_spacing=0.13,
                    specs=[[{'type': 'heatmap'}],
                           [{'type': 'table'}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z=df_corr_round.to_numpy(),
    x=df_corr.columns.tolist(),
    y=df_corr.index.tolist(),
    zmax=1, zmin=-1,
    showscale=True,
    colorbar=dict(lenmode='pixels',
                  len=300, 
                  yanchor='top', 
                  y=1),
    hoverongaps=True,
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header=dict(values=tbl.columns.tolist()), 
    cells=dict(values=tbl_data)
), row=2, col=1)

# add title
fig.update_layout(height=600,
                  width=600,
                  title_text='<i><b>Correlation round</b></i>')

z = df_corr_round.to_numpy()
x=df_corr.columns.tolist()
y=df_corr.index.tolist()

for n, row in enumerate(z):
    for m, val in enumerate(row):
        fig.add_annotation(text=str(zz[n][m]), x=x[m], y=y[n], xref='x1', yref='y1', showarrow=False)
        
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For the exclusion of 1.00 in the aggregate value, you may want to add a line for -1.00 and then take the total. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as a correct answer by clicking the check mark.